# Magento 2 - Override Swatches renderer.phtml

Tags: magento2, template, frontend, phtml

I would like to override file :

```
app/code/Magento/Swatches/view/frontend/templates/product/layered/renderer.phtml
```

In my own theme :

```
app/design/frontend/[VendorName]/[theme]/Magento_Swatches/templates/product/layered/renderer.phtml
```

It does not work. Is it a path problem? 
Do I copy it in the right place?

I followed this instruction but I think something is wrong for file I want to override : 
[Magento 2 - Override base view file](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/84550/magento-2-override-base-view-file)

Thank you in advance for your support.

I'm on Magento 2.3.1

Best regards, 
Florian

Comment: path seems correct to me. Please check theme is applied in which you overriding. If you are in production mode, you need to deploy content as well!

Comment: Hi @Pawan,

Thanks for your comment.
The theme is good, and I already deployed content.

But problem is still here :(

Thanks !